# Size of launcher icons for tablets

Tags: android, icons, size, launcher

I cannot find in any Android doc page where they talk about the size of the launcher icon for tablets.

I need to support 1024x600, 1280x800 and 1920x1200 tablets, so I guess 3 different launcher icons.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look up here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12768159/1458179

Answer (score 0):

There are no different launcher icons for Android Devices and Tablets. Launcher Icons are same for all devices in Android and their design sizes are defined at this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#icons_in_market). Have a reference at the link and design your launcher icons as per specifications. Launcher Icons sizes are differed as per device density but they are allways same shown in `48px x 48px` size.

Please be sure that Launcher Icon to be placed on Play Store will be of `512px x 512px` which is different from the launcher icon of the app.