# Cordova App -> iOS archive validation failed. Icon missing

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, archive

I'm trying to upload an `iOS app` I've developed using `Cordova`, but, when trying to `archive` I get this error:

[image: iOS cordova archive validation failed with errors]

What icon is missing and where should it go? (I have prepared a 72x72 px. icon)

PD: If you could tell me what name should it have would be great.

**EDIT:**

Here's what's inside my icon folder:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you built your Cordova project with the Cordova CLI, you should have an `icons` folder inside `yourProjectFolder/resources`. There you can find several default PNG icons with the Sencha logo on it, all of them have different size and are named accordingly (for example, there is one called `Icon~ipad.png` which happens to be 72x72 px). I beliebe this is where you whould put your custom icons for them to be packaged with your app.

EDIT 1 : I thought the Sencha build process would have packaged the content of this `resources` folder (at least the needed icons) to the targeted platforms resources folder under the `cordova` folder but apparently you've done it right so I guess all you can do now is dig into the `cordova` folder. You should try : `yourProjectFolder/cordova/www/resources/icons` (or maybe `yourProjectFolder/cordova/www/img`) or somewhere inside `yourProjectFolder/cordova/platforms/ios` (but having little experience with the ios platform using Cordova I can't think of a particular folder).

EDIT 2 : I made some tests and you indeed have to add the icons manually inside each platform folders within your `cordova` folder. For example, to add icons for an android app, go to `cordova/platforms/android/res` and add your `icon.png` file ([with the right width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12768159/3403161), specific to the targeted platform) inside each drawable folders. Then launch a build for your targeted platform (`cordova build android`) et voilà !

Comment: I'll edit so you can see what's inside that folder ;)

Comment: @Sascuash edited my answer accordingly. Unfortunately I think you'll have to try multiple places :/

Comment: I added icon~ipad.png and icon-ipad.png (different name) in all icon folders I found (2) in proyect, but still doesn't work