# Android launcher icon too small

Tags: android, icons, launcher, android-launcher

I have googled forever for a solutions to my problem.
My launcher icon is very small.
I have launcher icon, the original is 1100x1100 
but I have created the correct sizes using this online tool 
http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

I have then copied the png's to the correct res folders, but the icon is still TINY

I am using a android galaxy 3 (9305)

can I some how force the app to select another launcher

?

Comment: What's the width and height of your created icon? Does the picture have spaces on the sides?

Comment: Have you put icons in the correct folder? According to devices density I mean. drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi etc.

Comment: as stated in my text yes I put them in the correct folder. I have checked 1000 times. 
the sizes are 38,72,96,144 etc

Comment: Have you got a custom launcher that could change your icons shape and size?

Comment: no I just set the launcher in the manifest..

Comment: I too used http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/ for different sizes.. Facing the same prob. How did you solve your prob?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Check out this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12768159/3249477)

I've had a similar issue and the incorrect icon sizes were behind of it.

Scale the icons yourself to the appropriate sizes and see if it fixes your problems.

Answer (score 2):

[this][1]

[1]: https://makeappicon.com/ helps me.  help me.

upload the icon then after logo will be sent to your id then after download logo from your id  the after go to your project directory structure there will be folder of mdpi, xdpi etc.  then replace your folder to downloaded folder of mdpi, xhdpi....
then restart your android studio and run your app.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved with https://icon.kitchen/ (using 0 padding) obtaining icons in their file structure.
flutter_launcher_icons has been useless for me, icon too small: all my squared icon was resized and inscribed in the white circle placeholder of apps android screen.