# Error: 'F' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore

Tags: java, android

**Error:**

`'F' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" />
</set>
```

Where is the mistake? I do not see

Comment: `File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore`. I don't know what can be added.

Comment: @njzk2 Not being able to use capital letters seemed so arbitrary to me that I unconsciously disregarded this message for the first 20m of troubleshooting.

Comment: The error text refers to resource names (which I assume are what is contained in the file).  The cause of the error was resource filenames--which isn't the same.

Comment: I wanted to change my app's icon, so I tried to image asset from file menu, and mistakenly I gave that icon.jpg name as Icon.jpg as capitalize. So, I get this error. Please use lowercase for your file.jpg to solve your problem at the very beginning. I done with this solution, for example.

Comment: Simply use the lowercase character in the filename

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The error is not in the XML code but in the filename. Check the filenames in your res directories! Seems like one of the files has a capital 'F' in its filename.

Comment: Yes, this is a mistake. thank you

Comment: Glad to help! :) I'd be thankful if you mark my answer as correct and upvote it!

Comment: Why can't you have capitlizaed name?

Comment: Same here : had a 'N' in my Filename. Has this Filename convention changed over some Android version? Back in the days as ive made the app all went good but now it doesnt .. i gues only pepperidge farm remembers

Comment: I spent half an hour chasing a 'P' only to discover that it was in the XML filename.  Thanks!

Comment: This is really confusing ... Android Studio should warn when using capitals in resource names (although I see no sensible reason for this restriction).

Comment: they could have just said `no uppercase filenames`

Comment: This answer is not a proper answer to the error. I don't have any capital letters in the file names located in resources directory, still getting the error. And if you read the error carefully it is clearly said that 'not a valid file-based resource name', it's not a filename, may be in your case you had that wrong also, but that doesn't mean this is a proper answer to this error. And actually android studio doesn't allow you to create file names with capital letters in the resources directory, all those who commenting this are actually wrong, you all may have copy pasted those files.