# Change again the launcher logo in Android Studio 2.1.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I first built my Android application the launcher logo was automatically set to this:

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

which shows the Android logo. Now I changed it (with the instruction of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615889/how-to-change-the-launcher-logo-of-an-app-in-android-studio)) to a flashlight picture. If I try to run my app everything is working fine and it is the right launcher logo (flashlight).

But I decided to take a new launcher logo, so I deleted the whole new folder which was created in my `mipmap` folder. At first, I changed the android:icon in the `AndroidManifest.xml` back to the `ic_launcher`.

But if I try to run the app again, my launcher logo is still the flashlight. But it should be the Android logo. What did I do wrong?

I followed the instruction again and tried to add a new .png file, but now not even the new mipmap-folder is created.

Is there something else I need to consider?

Comment: Make sure you import the new file properly like this: **right-click on res folder -> new -> Image Asset** and then choose the image, leaving the asset type to be Launcher icons. Now the icon will be properly added to mipmap and will be there for every screen size (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi etc).

Comment: For my first Image I did the right-click on my **app** and added the new Image Asset. But it worked, so this cannot be the problem

Comment: Android Studio shows this hint: 'Some existing files will be overwritten by this operation. Files which replace existing files are marked red in the preview above.' And it doesn't matter which path I have selected for my image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve the problem by myself!

1. I did the right-click on the `app`-folder
2. I chose `New -> Image Asset`
3. I checked the `Image` Checkbox as `Asset Type` and selected my desired path

**BUT:**

I forgot to review the `Name`. So `ic_launcher` was still selected!

That's why I got the following errors:

> An icon with the same name already exists and will be overwritten.

And...

> Some existing files will be overwritten by this operation. Files which replace existing files are marked red in the preview above.

So what you need to do is simply change the name of your image to something that is not `flashlight` or `ic_launcher` (i.e. `flashlighttest` , `flashlight2` or `ic_launcher2`). Just make sure you will not overwrite an existing file!