# How to create my own icon in android launcher

Tags: android

I have my own application. And I need to make a function in my app, which will create my own icon in android launcher to some activity in this application. How can I do it? Thanks for your help.

P.S. I don't need to EDIT my current icon, I need to CREATE NEW icon with some params to my app (like intent), icon should have my own picture and text.

It's should work like chrome function "Add to home screen" which can add a website to your launcher.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615889/how-to-change-the-launcher-logo-of-an-app-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

you can change app icon in manifest

```
android:icon="@drawable/your_icon_image"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your icon to mipmap folder, then inside your manifest add this value inside application tag :

```
   <application
       ...
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       tools:replace="android:icon">
```

Also it's not recomanded to put it inside drawable folder, make sure it's inside mipmap folder.