# Partially changed launcher icon of android app

Tags: android

I have completed my first app and having problem with launcher icon.
I have repalced the default ic_launcher icon in mipmap folder with my own icon.
When i install the app, it shows the correct icon in phone's menu. But when i open application manager in phone , there it shows the default icon.
Also when i open shareit or xender there also my app has default icon.....

I have spent two days searching for answer and tried all suggestions..But none of them are working.....Please give me a solution....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is bad practice to just overwrite the icon this way. It is advisable to edit the AndroidManifest.xml file. In the application tag you will find `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"`, change it to the icon you want that is placed in the drawable folder. That way it will be applied everywhere.

For more information: [How to change the launcher logo of an app in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615889/how-to-change-the-launcher-logo-of-an-app-in-android-studio)

Comment: I got the solution......This problem is only there in Xiaomi phones.....it is working fine in other phones....thanks..