# How to disable adaptive icon in my project?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I use Android Studio 2.3.3, the target sdk api is 26.when I intall it to emulator I found it's forced to use adaptive-icon.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615889/how-to-change-the-launcher-logo-of-an-app-in-android-studio