# App Icon Launcher not showing in Android 7.1.1

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat

We are implementing a round icon (with a foreground and a background) and icon.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo" //normal logo
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo_o" //Our logo with foreground and background
    android:name=".MyApplication"/>
```

Works for every version but not for API 25

[image]

Our code for Foreground with Background is the next one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@mipmap/logo_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/logo_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

Comment: did you set the icon by just adding the image in mipmap resource file or used the image asset, which one you did?

Comment: I have the same exact issue, have you solved it?

Comment: @OlivierMercier I was having the same issue and just solved it https://stackoverflow.com/a/53199695/1245231

Answer (score 4):

**Reason:**

Android has support for adaptive icons on Android 8.0 (API level 26) and above. For more info check the following [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive). It looks like you didn't provide fallback images for devices on API level 25 and below.

**How to solve:**

Use adaptive icons only on API 26 and above and provide png's images of your app icon for older devices.

Your folder structure should be:

```
+-- _mipmap-anydpi-v26
|   +-- ic_launcher_round.xml
|   +-- ic_launcher.xml
+-- mipmap-mdpi
|   +-- ic_launcher_round.png
|   +-- ic_launcher.png
+-- mipmap-hdpi
|   +-- ic_launcher_round.png
|   +-- ic_launcher.png
+-- mipmap-xhdpi
|   +-- ic_launcher_round.png
|   +-- ic_launcher.png
+-- mipmap-xxhdpi
|   +-- ic_launcher_round.png
|   +-- ic_launcher.png
+-- mipmap-xxxhdpi
|   +-- ic_launcher_round.png
|   +-- ic_launcher.png
```

And configure them in your manifest as:

```
    <application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

The same content can be used for `ic_launcher_round.xml` and `ic_launcher.xml` because they are shaped by the OS. For example:

```
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

The png images `ic_launcher_round.png` and `ic_launcher.png` should contain the foreground and background layer in a single png and be shaped to the default and the round version of your app icon.

Answer (score 3):

Resource structure:

```
mipmap-anydpi-v25
   \  ic_launcher_round.xml
mipmap-anydpi-v26
   \  ic_launcher.xml
mipmap-*dpi
   \  ic_launcher.png
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
             android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

Add **resource redirection** for the `roundIcon` resource so that you are guaranteed to have the `v26` adaptive icon on API level 26+:

```
values-anydpi-v26
   \  drawables.xml
```

drawables.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <mipmap name="ic_launcher_round">@mipmap/ic_launcher</mipmap>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was caused by deleting PNG/bitmap versions of round icons.

I kept only the `mipmap-anydpi-v26` XML versions of the round icon. And deleted all the round icons in folders such as `mipmap-hdpi`, `mipmap-mdpi`, etc. thinking they are useless.

When round versions of PNG bitmaps are deleted it works fine on all Android versions (> 4.0) except Android 7.1 API level 25.

Answer (score 0):

You add other icons:

[image]

In manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".MiseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should regenerate with image asset in Android studio
For API 25, you should generate rounded icon

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by removing the `mipmap-anydpi-v25` folder.

Generating the icons again on the newest version of Android Studio I've noticed that Android Studio doesn't generate the `v25` folder, so I deleted it and it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate rounded icon with image asset in Android studio For any API .
For example in your case you have to generate it for API >=25.