# Logo appearance bad when multi-tab or in the more info app details

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

this is my first time introducing a logo, and I was wondering if is a bug when the appearance Logo when is multi-tab or in the more info app details appears the logo of Flutter, and if is there any way to replace the logo of Flutter for mine. For more details I use this package to insert the logo [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons#-readme-tab-).

I found that in the simulators works fine, but when I installed in my phone the issue I reported in this post, still happening

Android Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.candicemusic.candice">
<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="Candice"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

To see it more clear it, I saved some images.
[image][image][image]

Answer (score 2):

for android side : you can follow this [answer from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26615948/8623062). as it explains how to change android icon.

if you need further help/ eaiser way: you can use this [icon maker from romannurik](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html).

just upload the icon image you have, and customize it like whatever you want then download the file, unzip it and copy with replace in `\project_path\android\app\src\main\` and it's done

for ios you can get icons from [appiconmaker](https://appiconmaker.co/) and insert them from xcode

Answer (score 1):

*This is happening because you might not have updated your app's logo in your AndroidManifest.xml*

In `<application>` tag of your manifest there would be a parameter `android:icon` it's value should be updated and things will work fine for you.

#### __________________________________

#### See also:

[flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons): A command-line tool which simplifies the task of updating your Flutter app's launcher icon.

#### 1. Setup the config file

Add your Flutter Launcher Icons configuration to your pubspec.yaml or create a new config file called flutter_launcher_icons.yaml. 
    dev_dependencies: 
      flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"

```
flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon" 
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```

If you name your configuration file something other than flutter_launcher_icons.yaml or pubspec.yaml you will need to specify the name of the file when running the package.

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main -f <your config file name here>
```

Note: If you are not using the existing pubspec.yaml ensure that your config file is located in the same directory as it.

#### 2. Run the package

After setting up the configuration, all that is left to do is run the package.

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

[source of information](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)

## ____________________________

*In case if you have any doubts please let me know in the comments of this answer and if this answer helps you, don't forget to accept and up-vote it. Have a nice day :)*

Comment: Done it like 5 times and having the same problem :(

Comment: I found that in the simulators works fine, but when I installed in my phone the issue I reported in this post, still happening

Comment: Yes and also rebooting my phone

Comment: From your Android project can you find the flutter logo icon that is showing up for your app. Can you tell what is the file name for that logo and post the code for AndroidManifest ??

Comment: the things I found in the manifest is:
in <application>         `android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"`
and in  <meta-data>             `android:name="flutterEmbedding"`
Also in <activity>             `android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"`, hope this could help

Comment: Can you post your manifest code in your question ?? What is the value of android:icon parameter ??

Comment: Is @mipmap/ic_launcher the flutter logo or the logo that you are expecting to appear ??

Comment: in theory, the `@mipmap/ic_launcher` is the logo should appear, I changed the name of the file to check if a flutter logo is called the same way, but the problem persists

Comment: What if you delete Flutter logo from your project and see where the error is coming from and replace that piece of code with the file you want to show as your logo ?? Can you try this ??

Comment: I didn't find it :(