# How to change the app icon on android studio multiple times and nothing

Tags: java, android-studio

I have tried multiple times to change the app icon but to no use. If I click under the ic_launcher it shows my picture but when I run it it does not.
I have done the new image set way and the add manually into the andoid manifest.
Help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qouTS.png)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626912/18648400

Comment: This is likely already answered: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350624/set-icon-for-android-application

You also didn't provide any android / android studio / device version info.