# How can I get rid of transparent background space in (Android Asset Studio - Icon Generator)?

Tags: android, icons

When I upload my image (which has no background to begin with), it is automatically given transparent background no matter what settings I choose. I really like the "**Square**" shape (rounded corners) but there is way too much excess transparent background. When I see the icon on my phone it looks so small compared to Facebook for example. How can I get rid of this extra background space to make it as large as possible? Is one of my settings off?

[image]

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768128/launcher-icon-size/12768159#12768159

Comment: Is there any way to remove the padding in the icon generator though?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. Use GIMP or Photoshop. :3

Comment: Alright. Thank you. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious.

Answer (score 8):

http://reiszecke.github.io/AndroidAssetStudioFullsize/

Just click on `>> Launcher icons << Full Size edit`

pls mark as answer if it helped.

EDIT: only works on "bevel" and "none", I will adjust the other shapes at some point

Comment: Thanks! I guess you haven't had a chance to adjust the other shapes? I'd love to use the SQUARE option...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/icon_slayer/

Does the job but the an image must be provided first.

Creating the logo and background with **LIG** and loading the result in the gieson's **icon_slayer** should do it.