# Which size of icon should i use for ListView in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-icons

i have made List View with icon

so my question is which size of icon i mean **mdpi** **ldpi** **hdpi**

should i use??

Comment: "which size of icon i mean mdpi ldpi hdpi" -- those are not sizes. They are densities.

Answer (score -1):

- hdpi = 72x72
- mdpi = 48x48
- xhdpi = 96x96
- xxhdpi = 144x144
- xxxhdpi = 192x192

Someone answered the exact same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768128/launcher-icon-size) too.

Nevermind, I'm answering the wrong questions :) The answer above is for launcher icons.

You should follow [material design rules](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html).

You can check out the recommended resolutions/padding for icons in listviews there.