# ic_launcher Icon size in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

I replaced the default ic_launcher icon to another image, but I have a problem with the size of the icon and I cannot get the full size as shown in the bellow image.

[image]

Could anyone help me and tell me how to make the icon full size?

any help is appreciated??

Comment: did you created this image in android studio or from android assets store?

Comment: **APP ICON SIZES**
48 × 48 (mdpi)
72 × 72 (hdpi)
96 × 96 (xhdpi)
144 × 144 (xxhdpi)
192 × 192 (xxxhdpi)
512 × 512 (Google Play store)

Comment: check out [android iconography](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html)

Comment: did you try the solution given in my answer?

Comment: Thanks @MustanserIqbal for the replay,,, I used assests in Android studio,, the problem just the size of the icone,,, 
it seems to have something like padding or margin..

Comment: create a new icon with same process and check the option name trim surrounding blank space.and set the forground scaling to crop.. and i hope that will work

Comment: @MustanserIqbal I did what you said, still not solved :(

Comment: then i think you need to make image from android assets studio.

Comment: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html

you can create from here. that will definitely resolve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File -> New -> Image Asset

Select Launcher icons as asset type

choose high res image

and dont forget to tick the box that says "Trim surrounding blank space"

credits : [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768128/android-launcher-icon-size)

Comment: The problem is only with the size of the icone,, it looks like there is a padding or margin with the edges,, I don't know how to remove this padding!

Comment: you tried the solution in my answer? still having same problem?

Comment: Yes @Shreyans still not solved,,

The image that I have used is 512X512 px, does this size is alright??

Comment: can you upload original image? also try this site https://materialdesignicons.com/

Comment: In the manafest.xml- application tag, i have this: (android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher") it is alright???

Comment: Thanks so much Shreyans, I used your method + I also used Photoshop to remove the padding of each image..

Answer (score 0):

I found two solutions to get around the extra padding that Android Studio adds when creating icons:

1. Resize images using a [Windows] batch file.  This is the one I use because it's the easiest for me (on Windows):

   a. Create a ResizeImage.exe using the simple code from http://www.ianmcintyre.com/2014/06/c-resize-image-fit-image.html

   b. Save the following ResizeAndroidLauncherImage.bat file in the same directory as ResizeImage.exe.  This copies your original image to the various directories and resizes them:

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal

   set subdir=%2
   set iconsize=512
   if not exist "%subdir%" mkdir "%subdir%"
   copy /Y %1 %subdir%\ic_launcher-web.png
   %~dp0ResizeImage.exe %subdir%\ic_launcher-web.png %iconsize% %iconsize%

   set subdir=%2\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi
   set iconsize=192
   if not exist "%subdir%" mkdir "%subdir%"
   copy /Y %1 %subdir%\ic_launcher.png
   %~dp0ResizeImage.exe %subdir%\ic_launcher.png %iconsize% %iconsize%

   set subdir=%2\res\mipmap-xxhdpi
   set iconsize=144
   if not exist "%subdir%" mkdir "%subdir%"
   copy /Y %1 %subdir%\ic_launcher.png
   %~dp0ResizeImage.exe %subdir%\ic_launcher.png %iconsize% %iconsize%

   set subdir=%2\res\mipmap-xhdpi
   set iconsize=96
   if not exist "%subdir%" mkdir "%subdir%"
   copy /Y %1 %subdir%\ic_launcher.png
   %~dp0ResizeImage.exe %subdir%\ic_launcher.png %iconsize% %iconsize%

   set subdir=%2\res\mipmap-hdpi
   set iconsize=72
   if not exist "%subdir%" mkdir "%subdir%"
   copy /Y %1 %subdir%\ic_launcher.png
   %~dp0ResizeImage.exe %subdir%\ic_launcher.png %iconsize% %iconsize%

   set subdir=%2\res\mipmap-mdpi
   set iconsize=48
   if not exist "%subdir%" mkdir "%subdir%"
   copy /Y %1 %subdir%\ic_launcher.png
   %~dp0ResizeImage.exe %subdir%\ic_launcher.png %iconsize% %iconsize%

   endlocal
   ```

   c. Execute the batch file every time you update your icon:

   ```
   ResizeAndroidLauncherImage.bat [YourIcon.png] [YourAndreoidSRCDir]
   ```
2. Use the Android Asset Studio (https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html).  You'll have to modify the source to remove the extra padding.  See https://github.com/romannurik/AndroidAssetStudio/issues/73 for a discussion on how to do that. I tried this and used "none":

   ```
   const TARGET_RECTS_BY_SHAPE = { none: { x: 0, y: 0, w: 46, h: 46 }, circle: { x: 2, y: 2, w: 44, h: 44 }, square: { x: 5, y: 5, w: 38, h: 38 }, vrect: { x: 8, y: 2, w: 32, h: 44 }, hrect: { x: 2, y: 8, w: 44, h: 32 }, };
   ```

If I had Photoshop on my development machine, I would also try:

3. Record and play back a batch script in Photoshop.  [Note that I did not try this]