# Android ic_launcher icon is small in app list

Tags: android, android-studio, android-icons

I have a bit of a weird bug/issue with one of the apps I'm working on. On some devices running Android 6, the app icon is smaller in comparison to the rest of the icons from other apps.(See attachment) Any idea why?

I've checked and the ic_launcher have the right resolution - according to this: [Android - Launcher Icon Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768128/android-launcher-icon-size/12768159#12768159)

Probably also worth mentioning that the icons were generated using the icon generator within Android Studio.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Check to see if there is any padding left around the icon.

Comment: No, I don't think there is any padding around the icon

Comment: Random guess - have you stored the icon in the drawable or the mipmap folder? Mipmap would be correct.

Comment: The icons are in PNG format stored in the mipmap folders.

Comment: What HTC device are you testing on, and what density versions of your `mipmap` resource do you have?

Comment: @CommonsWare Seen on HTC M9 , Samsung A5 and Sony Z5 and I have mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi

Answer (score 2):

Drawables and mipmaps are nearly identical even mipmaps are mostly used for launcher icons and drawables for other things. The suffixes (e.g., -mdpi, -hdpi) are filters,
indicating under what circumstances the images stored in those directories should
be used. Specifically, -ldpi indicates images that should be used on devices with
low-density screens (around 120 dots-per-inch, or “dpi”). The -mdpi suffix indicates resources for medium-density screens (around 160dpi), -hdpi indicates resources for high-density screens (around 240dpi) and so on.

Android Studio offers an **Image Asset Wizard**. This wizard is designed to take a
starter image and give you icons, in a variety of densities.Android will calculate density of the screen on which app is installed and by that it will take the correct icon. If there is non than Android will take the nearest one. You can find more about mipmaps and drawables on official developer site or any relevant book about android programming like *The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development.*

There is **Android Asset Studio** which you can use in Chrome browser to generate your icons: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Answer (score 1):

it seems that the problem was the selected shape when generating the icon with the Images Asset tool in Android Studio. Square is selected by default. Selecting none fixed the issue.