# Best icon sizes to use for Android / iOS

Tags: android, ios, delphi, icons, timagelist

I'm writing Delphi app for android/iOS phone/tablet using TImageList.

My max icon size available is 96x96.
should I provide 3 sizes 24x24, 48x48, 72x72, 96x96
or
should I provide 3 sizes :
32x32, 64x64, 96x96
or
24x24, 48x48, 96x96
(is 3 more than sufficient?)

in TImageList.

thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768128/android-launcher-icon-size

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Sorry if I was not clear.  I was referring to icons used in buttons, components etc, not launcher icons.

Comment: Thanks for the link.

It says:

Action bar, Dialog & Tab icons

24 × 24 area in 32 × 32 (mdpi)
36 × 36 area in 48 × 48 (hdpi)
48 × 48 area in 64 × 64 (xhdpi)
72 × 72 area in 96 × 96 (xxhdpi)
96 × 96 area in 128 × 128 (xxxhdpi)*

What is meant by "24 × 24 area in 32 × 32"?

Does it mean that I create a 32x32 size but the actual icon picture
only occupies 24x24 inside this 32x32 pixels png?

Thanks.